# Can we use StackExchange flair on blog posts?

Tags: discussion, blog

Recently @joshmax asked in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4181579#4181579) if he could use SE flair on blog posts, instead of just DIY flair.

So what do you guys think? Should we only use DIY flair, or is SE flair acceptable as well?

### EDIT:

For example:

This is what we use now

[image: profile for Tester101 at Home Improvement, Q&A for contractors and serious DIYers]

Notice it only includes your stats for DIY.SE, and links back to the DIY.se user page.

---

This is what @joshmax wants to use

[profile for Tester101 on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/17329.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/17329)

Which includes stats from all Stack Exchange sites, and links back to the Stack Exchange user page.

Comment: It's not _necessarily_ that I **want** to use it, but I do think it looks more _"legitimate"_ (or _"full"_), if that makes any sense? :P Just sort of shows we're very active all across SE (at least for those who are on several SE sites it would).

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean the flair with the combined icons on it (for each site where you have more than 200 reputation)?  I would be good with that one.  I am assuming DIY would be included there as a user with 200 or more rep.